# Using a Python ML library for DJANGO APIView: loads model on every request

Tags: python, django, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to use this [python ML library](https://github.com/Shivanandroy/KeyPhraseTransformer) and turn it into an APIView for my project.

Although it works appropriately, It is taking around 20s to get the response while the [huggingface link](https://huggingface.co/snrspeaks/KeyPhraseTransformer) returns the same results in significantly less time.
As far as I know, the hugging face runs on CPU, takes ~20s only on first load and then only 1-2s after that.

I'm thinking maybe it's because this line: kp_model = KeyPhraseTransformer() is being called on every request, which is unnecessary as I just need to initiate the object once.

Any way on how to improve this?

#### services.py

```
from keyphrasetransformer import KeyPhraseTransformer

def extract_keyword(text):
    kp_model = KeyPhraseTransformer() 
    keyphrases = kp_model.get_key_phrases(text)
    return keyphrases
```

#### views.py

```
from .services import extract_keyword

class ExtractKeyphrase(APIView):
def post(self, request, format=None):
    try:
        text = request.data["text"]
        keyphrases = extract_keyword(text)
        return JsonResponse(keyphrases, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        Response("Request Failed", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using @lru_cache decorator for the model loading part that took the most time.

#### services.py

```
from functools import lru_cache
from keyphrasetransformer import KeyPhraseTransformer


@lru_cache(maxsize=2)
def load_model():
    kp_model = KeyPhraseTransformer()

    return kp_model


def extract_keyword(model, text):
    keyphrases = model.get_key_phrases(text)

    return keyphrases
```

#### views.py

```
from .services import load_model, extract_keyword

class ExtractKeyphrase(ApiAuthMixin, APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            text = request.data["text"]
            kp_model = load_model()
            keyphrases = extract_keyword(kp_model, text)

            return JsonResponse(keyphrases, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            Response("Request Failed", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```